# iOS: The first Silent push notification does not work after rebooting device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, silent

In my app, I use Silent Push Notification for new messages. However, I found that the first Silent Push Notification doesn't work in following cases:

Case1:
 1. Login app
 2. Turn off the device
 3. Send a message to logged in account
 4. Turn on the device
 5. Receive a silent push notification, check the app's log, it wasn't woken up.

Case2:
 1. Login app
 2. Turn off the network connection
 3. Send a message to the logged in account
 4. Resume the network connection
 5. Receive a silent push notification, check the app's log, it wasn't woken up.

From the packets I got, it seems that this issue ONLY happens when the 3 packets marked "RST" are inserted by other kinds of packets sent to APN server

Thanks in advance who can provide any help!

Best wishes!

Comment: and the question is?